# How do I make this CSS drawing responsive, provided its container is already responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a monitor design using pure CSS. Currently, I have this:

[CSS Monitor Design Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stngL8hc/)

It looks ok, but if you play around with the screen size, the design itself is not responsive. Its parent container is responsive, thanks to [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/).

Now, I want to do these things:

- Make the design responsive and fit to any screen size.
- Maintain the aspect ratio of the screen. This is the main problem. I tried things like width: 100%, however, without a fixed height, things dont work.
- Finally, I want the monitor base to be wired, that is, I want the trapezium to only have borders and not a fill color.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

My code:

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="monitor-container">
                <div class="monitor-top">
                    <div class="screen-content">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="monitor-base">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.monitor-container {
                margin: 25px;
                padding: 25px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            .monitor-top {
                margin: auto;
                width: 400px;
                height: 250px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .screen-content {
                margin: 25px;
                width: 350px;
                height: 200px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            .monitor-base {
                margin: 0 auto;
                border-bottom: 50px solid black;
                border-left: 25px solid transparent;
                border-right: 25px solid transparent;
                height: 0; 
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }
```

For the boilerplate, I am using these:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhg/Skeleton/master/css/normalize.css

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhg/Skeleton/master/css/skeleton.css

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: This way https://jsfiddle.net/stngL8hc/1/ ... you can try with % and padding to keep the aspect

Answer (score 2):

To do the trapezium you need to put another trapezium over the top to give a wired effect. The way you have done it with borders can't be utilised in itself to have a wired feel.

add this line

```
<div class="monitor-base">
      **<div class="mb2">
      </div>**
            </div>
```

and the css like this

```
 .mb2 {
        position:relative;
        left:-22px;
        top:2px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-bottom: 45px solid white;
            border-left: 22px solid transparent;
            border-right: 22px solid transparent;
            height: 0; 
            width: 100px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
```

to have a wired effect.

The aspect ratio is something you would need to use a javascript preprocessor for I think, in vanilla css I don't think it is possible to maintain the aspect ratio as the height and width are independent, however in scss or less you can tie them together. I think.